# Find Object in Vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have been trying to figure out what the best way to find an object in a vector. Currently I am attempting to use find on this object:

```
class Category
{
public:
  string modeType;
  vector<VideoMode> videoModes;

  Category(){}

  Category(string name) 
  {
     modeType = name;
  }

  friend bool operator== ( const Category &c1, const string &c2 )
  {
     return c1.modeType == c2;
  }

};
```

and this is my find:

```
vector<Category>::iterator category = find(modes.begin(), modes.end(), Category("Name"));
```

I am getting an error when I try to compile saying that there is "No operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type "Category" for "==" I looked into the algorithm header and found the find code:

```
template<class _InIt,
class _Ty> inline
_InIt _Find(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, const _Ty& _Val)
{   // find first matching _Val
for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
    if (*_First == _Val)
        break;
return (_First);
}
```

I am not really sure where to go from here though. Any advise would be appreciated, I don't know C++ that well :(

Comment: It shouldn't really be a friend function if it only accesses public members. Make it a non-friend free function, and I'd take `Category` for both parameters. If it's called with a `string`, it will be converted. The only thing that might mess with are string literals (at least until we get the s suffix on them).

Comment: Changing it to Category from string made it work, and thanks for the advice. If you post it as an answer I can accept it as the best answer, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `operator==` to take a `Category` and a `std::string`, but you're trying to find a `Category`, which `operator==` is not defined for. In this case, you *could* just pass the string literal:

```
find(modes.begin(), modes.end(), "Name")
```

However, I would suggest changing the equality operator to take another `Category`. Comparing two objects of the same type is logical, and this way works when the string is on the left without an extra overload, since your type is implicitly convertible from a `std::string`. I also suggest not making it a friend since it doesn't access anything more than public members:

```
bool operator==(const Category &lhs, const Category &rhs) {
    return lhs.modeType == rhs.modeType;
}
```

To use this with `std::find` will work the way you have it, but not if you pass a string literal. This is because it would have to go through two user-defined conversions to reach your class (`std::string` then your class), but only one can be performed. Keeping overloads down, the nicest solution once C++14 comes along would be to make use of the new literal suffixes:

```
find(modes.begin(), modes.end(), "Name"s)
                                 ^std::string because of the s
```

For now, it's always possible to define your own `_s` that does the same. I personally prefer the user adding a `s` or `_s` to putting in two more overloads or overloading the constructor to take types that `std::string` is constructible from. That feels like pointless extra work and just increases the possibility of an ambiguity.